# std::map Iterator increment segfault

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, gdb, coredump

I have a code snippet which looks like this:

```
typename C::iterator it = container->begin();
while (it != container->end()) {
  typename C::iterator curIt = it;
  ++it;
  if (!pred(*curIt)) {
    container->erase(curIt);
  }
}
```

The type of the container when I'm using it is `std::map` and I get a (rare) crash due to segfault when `++it;` is executed.

Relevant piece of the stack trace looks like this:

```
0x0000000000b0f000 in operator++ (this=<synthetic pointer>) at ..../libgcc/4.8.1/gcc-4.8.1-glibc-2.17-fb/8aac7fc/include/c++/4.8.1/bits/stl_tree.h:189
```

**What could be possible reasons for the crash?**

---

Other potentially useful pieces of information

(1) This is supposed to be single-threaded code, so the map getting modified in parallel shouldn't be a possibility.

(2) `pred` takes in `const std::pair<Key, Value>&` so it shouldn't be modifying the map in any way.

(3) When I run gdb on the core dump, I get

```
(gdb) print curIt
$3 = <optimized out>
(gdb) print it
$4 = {_M_node = 0x78b80e0 <dwarf_cie_info_pool>}
(gdb) print *it
Attempt to take address of value not located in memory.
```

How do I interpret this and any suggestions on how to extract more useful information from gdb?

Comment: @TonyD Hmm, that might be something broken with the implementation, actually. I don't think `erase()` for associative containers is allowed to invalidate the end iterator.

Comment: There's a very nice implementation of container erasure in [N4161](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4161.htm), which is going to be in the Library Fundamentals 2 TS.

Comment: @TonyD I agree with T.C. - my understanding is that `container->end()` would not be changed due to an `erase()`

Comment: Try defining `_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` and see if you get anything from the debug checks.

Comment: Can you provide a complete example that can be pasted as-is?

Comment: @user657267 Unfortunately I don't have a complete example as this is part of a much larger codebase.

Comment: @T.C. Whats `_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` - any documentation I can read up about this?

Comment: @T.C. yeah - good point - in a compliant implementation `erase()` isn't allowed to invalidate an earlier snapshot of `end()`....

Comment: Have you tried `print *container` in gdb?  Does it happen if you compile without optimisation, so you can inspect `curIt`?  Can you step through it - does it happen on the first / any / last element, and is only immediately after an `erase`?  Perhaps put some trace/log statements in if debugging interactively is hard to do.

Comment: @vigs1990 `_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` puts libstdc++ in debug mode. See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/debug_mode.html

Comment: I looked at libstdc++'s implementation, and its design guarantees that the end iterator will remain valid as required by the standard. Since this code is correct as written, I'm inclined to think that the problem must be somewhere else. Possibly a memory corruption bug somewhere.

Comment: I recommend just trying valgrind.  It is the quickest way to find memory errors, which this probably is.  And either disable optimization or use -Og.  This should reduce how often you see <optimized out>.